# Getting filename with out extension using SQL query in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an issue while getting the file name with out extension from a column in SQL table like this.

The column name is `[image]` in `dbo.emp` table and the values are:

```
temp.jpg
test1.jpg
test1.jpeg
sample.jpg
sample1.gif
```

Now I want to get only `temp`, `test1`, `sample`, `sample1` without the extension `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, etc…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    SUBSTRING([image], 0, charindex('.', [image], 0)) 
from 
    [table]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(32);
SET @x = 'temp.jpg';
SELECT SUBSTRING(@x, 1, CHARINDEX('.', @x)-1);
-- or SELECT LEFT(@x, CHARINDEX('.', @x)-1);
```

Result:

```
temp
```

This doesn't specify what to do if a `.` is not found, however. If you want to deal with that and return th whole string when no `.` is found:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE([image] VARCHAR(32));
INSERT @x SELECT 'temp.jpg' UNION ALL SELECT 'sample1.gif' UNION ALL SELECT 'foo';
SELECT SUBSTRING([image], 1, COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.', [image]),0)-1, 32)) FROM @x;
```

Results:

```
temp
x
foo
```

Comment: Why start at index 1 and then subtract? Also, if no '.' is found, this throws an exception which isn't exactly ideal in a query...

Comment: @Dave before your comment I had already added handling for no `.`. Also the starting at index 1 is just habit, since the first character = character 1, and that maps to how LEFT treats it.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
left(fn, len(fn) - charindex('.', reverse(fn)))
```

E.g.

```
;with T (fn) as (
    select ''            union
    select 'aaa'         union
    select 'aaa.bbb'     union
    select 'aaa.bbb.ccc'
)
select left(fn, len(fn) - charindex('.', reverse(fn))) from T
```

For

```
(No column name)

aaa
aaa
aaa.bbb
```

Comment: +1 because your answer covers all possible situations: no '.' or multiple '.' in file name